# Powershell Dialog Box to select ping computer lists

Tags: powershell, ping

I'll be saying this for awhile, but again I'm a few months into scripting and I stumbled across a dialog box script on technet (tip of the week) and I am hoping to alter it so that I can select a computer lists from the box click ok and it will ping the computers in that list.  Here's a copy of the code.

```
[void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms")
[void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Drawing") 

$objForm = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form 
$objForm.Text = "Select List"
$objForm.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(300,200) 
$objForm.StartPosition = "CenterScreen"

$objForm.KeyPreview = $True
$objForm.Add_KeyDown({if ($_.KeyCode -eq "Enter") 
{$x=$objListBox.SelectedItem;$objForm.Close()}})
$objForm.Add_KeyDown({if ($_.KeyCode -eq "Escape") 
{$objForm.Close()}})

$OKButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$OKButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(75,120)
$OKButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(75,23)
$OKButton.Text = "OK"
$OKButton.Add_Click({$x=$objListBox.SelectedItem;$objForm.Close()})
$objForm.Controls.Add($OKButton)

$CancelButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$CancelButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(150,120)
$CancelButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(75,23)
$CancelButton.Text = "Cancel"
$CancelButton.Add_Click({$objForm.Close()})
$objForm.Controls.Add($CancelButton)

$objLabel = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$objLabel.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(10,20) 
$objLabel.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(280,20) 
$objLabel.Text = "Please select a List:"
$objForm.Controls.Add($objLabel) 

$objListBox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ListBox 
$objListBox.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(10,40) 
$objListBox.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(260,20) 
$objListBox.Height = 80

[void] $objListBox.Items.Add("AXIS BLY")
[void] $objListBox.Items.Add("AXIS LYN")
[void] $objListBox.Items.Add("GS 5 List")
[void] $objListBox.Items.Add("GS 6 List")
[void] $objListBox.Items.Add("Computer List")


$objForm.Controls.Add($objListBox) 

$objForm.Topmost = $True

$objForm.Add_Shown({$objForm.Activate()})
[void] $objForm.ShowDialog()

$x
```

Comment: Cool story bro... Did you have a question?

Comment: The computers list is in a files or where else?

Comment: Sorry my question is this, I have multiple computer lists and I'm not clear on how to make the selection initiate the action of pinging the computer list.

Comment: So `$x` stores the name of the selected list. It's just a string with the name of a list. Where are the lists stored and in what format?

Comment: The lists are .txt and I have them currently stored in the same directory as my scripts. (C:\Users\501289523\Documents\scripts).  I may be way over my head, due to my level of experience with powershell scripting, however I enjoy a challenge and learning new things.

Answer (score 0):

```
switch($x) {
"AXIS BLY"  {Write-Output "do AXIS BLY List" }
"AXIS LYN"  {Write-Output "do AXIS Lyn List" }
"GS 5 List" {Write-Output "do GS 5 List"     }
"GS 6 List" {Write-Output "do GS 6 List" }
"Computer List" {Write-Output "do Computer List" }


    default { }
}
```

Replace Write-Output "..." with the commands you want processed.